# How to find a object in array React native

Tags: arrays, react-native, sorting, arraylist

I have array=

```
[{

        "2022-12-06": [{
            "student": "10",
            "duration": "00:00:07",
            "intervals": "1"
        }]
    },
    {

        "2022-09-08": [{
                "student": "20",
                "duration": "00:00:07",
                "intervals": "1"
            },
            {
                "student": "300",
                "duration": "00:00:07",
                "intervals": "1"
            },
            {
                "student": "10",
                "duration": "00:00:07",
                "intervals": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {

        "date20221208": [{
                "student": "10",
                "duration": "00:00:07",
                "intervals": "1"
            },
            {
                "student": "10",
                "duration": "00:00:07",
                "intervals": "1"
            },
            {
                "student": "10",
                "duration": "00:00:07",
                "intervals": "1"
            },
            {
                "student": "10",
                "duration": "00:00:07",
                "intervals": "1"
            },
            {
                "student": "10",
                "duration": "00:00:07",
                "intervals": "1"
            }

        ]
    }
]
```

I want find a date and return value date is exits or not
for eg.
i find 2022-12-06 if array have this value then true if not then false

I want find a date and return value date is exits or not
for eg.
i find 2022-12-06 if array have this value then true if not then false

Answer (score 1):

First of all this question is not about react-native. This is about **basic javascript**.

You can use Array.Prototype.find() method.

```js
const arr = [{

        "2022-12-06": [{
            "student": "10",
            "duration": "00:00:07",
            "intervals": "1"
        }]
    },
    {

        "2022-09-08": [{
                "student": "20",
                "duration": "00:00:07",
                "intervals": "1"
            },
            {
                "student": "300",
                "duration": "00:00:07",
                "intervals": "1"
            },
            {
                "student": "10",
                "duration": "00:00:07",
                "intervals": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {

        "date20221208": [{
                "student": "10",
                "duration": "00:00:07",
                "intervals": "1"
            },
            {
                "student": "10",
                "duration": "00:00:07",
                "intervals": "1"
            },
            {
                "student": "10",
                "duration": "00:00:07",
                "intervals": "1"
            },
            {
                "student": "10",
                "duration": "00:00:07",
                "intervals": "1"
            },
            {
                "student": "10",
                "duration": "00:00:07",
                "intervals": "1"
            }

        ]
    }
]

const checkArray = (str) => {
  const x = arr.find(item => item.hasOwnProperty(str))
  return x ? true:false
  // or return object.If has not return undefined
  // return x
}

console.log(checkArray("2022-12-06"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Array.prototype.find() method to search for an object in an array. This method returns the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function.

For example, if you have an array of objects and you want to find an object with a specific date property, you could use the find() method like this:

```
const array = [{date: '2022-12-06', name: 'John'}, {date: '2020-02-05', name: 'Jane'}, {date: '1990-04-07', name: 'Bob'}];

const object = array.find(obj => obj.date === '2022-12-06');

console.log(object); // {date: '2022-12-06', name: 'John'}
```

Comment: const array =[{

        "2022-12-06": [{
            "student": "10",
            "duration": "00:00:07",
            "intervals": "1"
        }]
    }] then I can use above code